# Create a Bucket in Simperium using http

Tags: actionscript-3, http, cloud, simperium

I try to create a bucket so that I can then create and load an object to the bucket but cannot find a way to create a bucket using the http api.

I tried to create the object according the sample but only get a response code of 400 back.
When calling the bucket list, I get an empty result list.

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 means 'bad request, check input data'. Is it possible that the data is not properly formated as a JSON document?.